# Angular 2 in Plunker can't see my component in route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, plunker

I'm sure it's probably something ridiculously simple that I'm missing, but I can't seem to figure out what it is. I have a plunker that apparently can't see my "HomeComponent" for the route I have defined. As far as I can tell, I've followed some examples I've seen, but clearly I've missed something and I can't see what. Can anyone see the issue here?

http://plnkr.co/edit/eRWqYBrwXKiNXhlDRyHZ?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router'
import {HomeComponent} from '../home/home'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './src/app.html'
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HomeComponent, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the issues. 
Your SystemJs config file is looking for `app` in the `./src` folder.

So first you need to place your home component inside the `src` folder:

`src/home/home.html` and `src/home/home.ts`

Then, to load the template, SystemJs is not looking for the relative url from the component itself but from the `index.html`, so you need to change your home component to:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   templateUrl: 'src/home/home.html'
})

export class HomeComponent {}
```

And in the app module include `HomeComponent` as part of the declarations:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  declarations: [ App, HomeComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[See it in plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dN1lOx1vMOTYXzNhQJvk).

Comment: I also had to change my declarations, which I saw in your example. I think I had tried to put "HomeComponent" into my imports instead of declarations before that, but of course my paths were messed up also. I had tried to fix the paths, but then I hadn't fixed my declarations. Thanks.

Comment: yw! I'll update my answer to include the declaration. I forgot to include that after I added it in the plunker before posting.

For the route, what about just deleting the route that includes the app component? app is the component that is bootstrapped so you don't really need a route for it.

const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }]; should do it.